# Unique subset of 3 items

Tags: javascript

Given a set of X items write an algorithm to obtain every combination of possible permutations to output unique subsets of 3 items. Order is irrelevant, {A B C} is the same as {B A C} 
Example: Input: {ABCD} Output: {ABC}, {ABD}, {ACD}, {BCD}

```js
const sizeSubsets = function(input) {
  size = input.length;
  for(let i = 1; i < size-1; i++)
    for(let j = i + 1; j < size-1; j++)
      for(let k = j + 1; k < size-1; k++)
        console.log("{"+input[i]+input[j]+input[k]+"}");
}
const input = "{ABCD}";
sizeSubsets(input);
```

the above standard solution gives required result but , I the time, space complexity costs high and if I am correct it it O(n).

Can it be better( alternative solution)?

Comment: what you have is O(n^3), definitely not O(n)

Comment: possible dupication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614876/find-all-unique-subsets-of-a-set-of-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all unique subsets of a set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614876/find-all-unique-subsets-of-a-set-of-values)